# can neo4j find the shortest n paths by Traversals with index?

Tags: neo4j

I read the wiki api  from http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/rest-api-traverse.html
and check my code, i can find the shortest n paths by Traversals ,and can find nodes or relationships with index. but my projects has 300M nodes ,when i find  shortest n paths by Traversals ,like retionship data property Name contain 'hi' ,if i use neo4j's fiter method,it is really slow,i want use index(i created it!),code like:

```
  {
      "order" : "breadth_first",
      "return_filter" : {
        "body" : "position.endNode().getProperty('name').toLowerCase().contains('t')",
        "language" : "javascript"
      },
      "prune_evaluator" : {
        "body" : "position.length() > 10",
        "language" : "javascript"
      },
      "uniqueness" : "node_global",
      "relationships" : [ {
        "direction" : "all",
        "type" : "knows"
      }, {
        "direction" : "all",
        "type" : "loves"
      } ],
      "max_depth" : 3
    }
```

**i want :**

```
{
  "order" : "breadth_first",
  "return_filter" : {
    "body" : "position.endNode().name:*hi*",
    "language" : "javascript"
  },
  "prune_evaluator" : {
    "body" : "position.length() > 10",
    "language" : "javascript"
  },
  "uniqueness" : "node_global",
  "relationships" : [ {
    "direction" : "all",
    "type" : "knows"
  }, {
    "direction" : "all",
    "type" : "loves"
  } ],
  "max_depth" : 3
}
```

can someone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it slow the first time or are consecutive requests equally slow? Properties are loaded per node/relationship the first time any property is requested for that node/relationship and maybe you're seeing that performance hit.

I think that using an index would help for nodes that haven't been loaded yet, but not otherwise. Doing this in rest could be tricky in that you'd have to do index lookup before hand and pass that list into the evaluator. But that doesn't scale. Instead could write an extension for this?

Comment: thank your @user211920 ，the relationship has *big data* like long string ,length more than 1000,i'd like search  query with index by lucene. the first time i don't care because i will load all data in memory.any idea?thank you

Comment: perhaps you should turn your approach around, do a fulltext index with those nodes, find them via an index lookup and then check if they have the correct relationships and age.